# rake cache:clear says it's removing files but it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, caching, rake

In cron and the command prompt I run `bundle exec rake cache:clear` and it logs all the files in my cache directory and that it's removing them but it is not. 
The files are still there and I can remove them with a remove command. I've confirmed it has file permissions. What else could it be?

```
    About your application's environment
Ruby version              2.1.2 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          2.2.2
Rack version              1.5
Rails version             4.0.9
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Active Record version     4.0.9
Action Pack version       4.0.9
Action Mailer version     4.0.9
Active Support version    4.0.9
Middleware                Airbrake::UserInformer, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, Refraction, #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007ffa821bb0c8>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, Airbrake::Rails::Middleware, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag
Application root          /mnt/www/ride/releases/20150519225426
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql
```

The user is deploy in the deploy group.

```
$ ls -l
total 18216
-rw-r--r-- 1 deploy deploy    415 May 27 16:25 03eea388375a06041afe40e5eb9585b5e4af182e.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 deploy deploy   5424 May 27 16:25 04601c02ebf36c331e3908c4cf06771d6fab1f84.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 deploy deploy   5416 May 27 16:25 052678a2ef02de2e241574857f17927afc4ed3fb.cache
...
```

This is the user that runs the cron job. Here is the output of the command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake cache:clear --silent

***** initializing cache clear *****

***** deleting /social *****



***** deleting main cache *****

/var/www/site/tmp/cache/81d0fc6f96d4c6c957a26c932e3f2b471a56bc82.cache
/var/www/site/tmp/cache/1db90a7553f8440babe0f23932a674096184feb2.cache
/var/www/site/tmp/cache/b6d4cb2a18a5599605fec8880fc08d8604cbba07.cache
```

---

I can log in as the deploy user and reproduce this behavior. Performing the rake tasks lists out the files but wont delete them. Using the rm command I can successfully remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was to use

```
rake tmp:clear
```